# Error starting Django CMS project in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-14.04, django-cms, python-imaging-library

The problem arises when I try to start a project Django CMS with the command:

```
djangocms -p . mysite
```

This is the error:

```
Database configuration (in URL format) [default sqlite://localhost/project.db]: 
django CMS version (choices: 2.4, 3.0, 3.1, stable, develop) [default stable]: 
Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, stable) [default stable]: 
Activate Django I18N / L10N setting (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Install and configure reversion support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Languages to enable. Option can be provided multiple times, or as a comma separated list. Only language codes supported by Django can be used here: en
Optional default time zone [default Europe/Madrid]: 
Activate Django timezone support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Activate CMS permission management (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Use Twitter Bootstrap Theme (choices: yes, no) [default no]: 
Use custom template set [default no]: 
Load a starting page with examples after installation (english language only). Choose "no" if you use a custom template set. (choices: yes, no) [default no]: 
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
Dependencies installed
Creating the projectFailure occurred. Do you want to cleanup by removing /home/alberto/Documentos/PouBlog? [Y/N] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alberto/.virtualenvs/PouBlog/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/alberto/.virtualenvs/PouBlog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 53, in execute
    install.cleanup_directory(config_data)
  File "/home/alberto/.virtualenvs/PouBlog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 92, in cleanup_directory
    if strtobool(choice) or config_data.noinput:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/util.py", line 325, in strtobool
    raise ValueError, "invalid truth value %r" % (val,)
ValueError: invalid truth value ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The invalid truth value '' occurred due to no selection passed in the last question

```
Creating the projectFailure occurred. Do you want to cleanup by removing /home/alberto/Documentos/PouBlog? [Y/N]
```

In my case the issue was with PIL library which was not build using JPEG support, which can be fixed using following steps:

Install related libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
sudo apt-get install libqd-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Reinstall PIL and CMS:

```
pip install -U --force Pillow
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps djangocms-installer
```

In case above doesnt work to fix PIL then try the following to correctly build PIL library:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
```

Get the Imaging/PIL library:

```
wget http://effbot.org/media/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz
```

Extract Imaging tar and Modify  Imaging-1.1.6/_imagingft.c :

```
tar -zxvf Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz; cd Imaging-1.1.6; 
python setup.py build 
Error observed: 
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o
```

_imagingft.c:68:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
Change the above line to: 
    #include

Retar and install

```
tar -zcvf Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz Imaging-1.1.6
pip install -U --force Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz
```

Now follow the djangocms steps again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that when CMS installer asked me the languages I answer with the languages separated by ', '. 
When I try again and put the languages separated only by ',' it worked properly.